# Syntax error in update query in VB .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to run a SQL command in VB .NET but it returns a error message of syntax error in my string variable which I just not able to figure out by myself since this is my first experience for programming with SQL command.The specific message is:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query express '= '045617123'.

Where "045617123" is the data stored in one of the data fields

Can someone please help me out from this? Thank You

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim constr As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Users\JohnnyCheng\Documents\GradeBook.accdb"
    Dim conobj As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)
    Dim da1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim da2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim sqlstr1 As String = ""
    Dim sqlstr2 As String = ""
    conobj.Open()
    For i As Integer = 0 To vt1.Rows.Count - 1
        sqlstr1 = "UPDATE Students SET LastName = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(1) & "', FirstName = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(2) & "', StreetAddress = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(3) & "', City = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(4) & "', State = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(5) & "', ZipCode = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(6) & "' WHERE = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(0) & "'"
        da1.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr1, conobj)
        da1.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    'For i As Integer = 0 To vt2.Rows.Count - 1
    'sqlstr2 = "UPDATE Grades SET FirstExam = " & vt2.Rows(i)(1) & ", SecondExam = " & vt2.Rows(i)(2) & ", FinalExam = " & vt2.Rows(i)(3) & "WHERE StID = " & vt1.Rows(i)(0)
    'da2.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, conobj)
    'da2.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'Next
    conobj.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlParameters`. If some of your datafields contain `'` charachter then sql query return a syntax error. Or users can create a [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) query.

Your syntax error in the `WHERE = '" & vt1.Rows(i)(0) & "'"` There are no column name which must be same as datafield value

Here example of using parameters:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim constr As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Users\JohnnyCheng\Documents\GradeBook.accdb"

    Dim query as New StringBuilder()
    With query
        .AppendLine("UPDATE Students SET LastName = @LastName")
        .AppendLine(", FirstName = @FirstName")
        .AppendLine(", StreetAddress = @StreetAddress")
        .AppendLine(", City = @City")
        .AppendLine(", State  = @State")
        .AppendLine(", ZipCode = @ZipCode")
        .AppendLine("WHERE YourIDField = @ID;")
    End With
    Using conobj As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)
        conobj.Open()
        Dim da1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
        For i As Integer = 0 To vt1.Rows.Count - 1
            Using updCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query.ToString(), New OleDb.OleDbConnection(""))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", vt1.Rows(i)(1)) 
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName ", vt1.Rows(i)(2))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetAddress ", vt1.Rows(i)(3))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City ", vt1.Rows(i)(4))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State ", vt1.Rows(i)(5))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", vt1.Rows(i)(6))
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", vt1.Rows(i)(0))
                da1.UpdateCommand = updCommand
                da1.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: That code missing of required data field was so stupid... Thank you so much for help me out from this problem. It might take me some time to master the SQL parameters it's looks very useful! Thank you for the suggestions XD